# Android specific ADT dependencies missing

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to add the ADT Plugin 11.0.0 on Eclipse 3.6.2, but I keep getting several errors. Isn't eclipse supposed to resolve all dependencies automatically. How should I add all the dependencies needed by Android?

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Android Development Tools 11.0.0.v201105251008-128486 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 11.0.0.v201105251008-128486)
Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 11.0.0.v201105251008-128486 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 11.0.0.v201105251008-128486) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

Comment: I know its not good that i am asking you that, but have you installed SDK properly

Comment: I did using installer_r11-windows.exe